# How To Add Docker Container Static Route?

Tags: networking, server, docker, routing, subnet

Have a server with 4 subnets - 1 usable IP, each configured on separate network port on the network card. Running 4 docker containers, but they are randomly accessible upon reboot. How to add a static route for each?

```
container1 - network card port1 - Subnet/IP1
container2 - network card port2 - Subnet/IP2
container3 - network card port3 - Subnet/IP3
container4 - network card port4 - Subnet/IP4
```

the route of docker for now is: `172.17.0.0/16 dev docker0 proto kernel scope link src 172.17.0.1`

I need each docker container to use a separate port, network (IP).